# Disable HTML within XML escaping with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, sinatra, nokogiri

I'm trying to parse an XML document from the Google Directions API.

This is what I've got so far:

```
x = Nokogiri::XML(GoogleDirections.new("48170", "48104").xml)
x.xpath("//DirectionsResponse//route//leg//step").each do |q|
  q.xpath("html_instructions").each do |h|
    puts h.inner_html
  end
end
```

The output looks like this:

```
Head &lt;b&gt;south&lt;/b&gt; on &lt;b&gt;Hidden Pond Dr&lt;/b&gt; toward &lt;b&gt;Ironwood Ct&lt;/b&gt;
Turn &lt;b&gt;right&lt;/b&gt; onto &lt;b&gt;N Territorial Rd&lt;/b&gt;
Turn &lt;b&gt;left&lt;/b&gt; onto &lt;b&gt;Gotfredson Rd&lt;/b&gt;
...
```

I would like the output to be:

```
Turn <b>right</b> onto <b>N Territorial Rd</b>
```

The problem seems to be Nokogiri escaping the html within the xml

I trust Google, but I think it would be also good to sanitize it further to:

```
Turn right onto N Territorial Rd
```

But I can't (using [sanitize](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize) perhaps) without the raw xml. Ideas?

Comment: Could you try calling:  `original_content()`?  puts h.original_content, got the idea from here: http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/EntityDecl.html not sure if it helps

Comment: That doesn't work, but just `content()` does. Thanks!

Comment: Please add a *SMALL* sample of the XML you are working with. That will help us help you.

Comment: Here is some [xml](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&sensor=false) from Google. As I said before, `h.content` (and `h.inner_text`) solve this issue. If someone could explain why I would love to accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because I don't have the Google Directions API installed I can't access the XML, but I have a strong suspicion the problem is the result of telling Nokogiri you're dealing with XML. As a result it's going to return you the HTML encoded like it should be in XML.

You can unescape the HTML using something like:

```
CGI::unescape_html('Head &lt;b&gt;south&lt;/b&gt; on &lt;b&gt;Hidden Pond Dr&lt;/b&gt; toward &lt;b&gt;Ironwood Ct&lt;/b&gt;')
=> "Head <b>south</b> on <b>Hidden Pond Dr</b> toward <b>Ironwood Ct</b>\n"
```

`unescape_html` is an alias to `unescapeHTML`:

```
 Unescape a string that has been HTML-escaped
  CGI::unescapeHTML("Usage: foo "bar" <baz>")
     # => "Usage: foo \"bar\" "
```

---

I had to think about this a bit more. It's something I've run into, but it was one of those things that escaped me during the rush at work. The fix is simple: You're using the wrong method to retrieve the content. Instead of:

```
puts h.inner_html
```

Use:

```
puts h.text
```

I proved this using:

```
require 'httpclient'
require 'nokogiri'

# This URL comes from: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#XML
url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=Chicago,IL&destination=Los+Angeles,CA&waypoints=Joplin,MO|Oklahoma+City,OK&sensor=false'
clnt = HTTPClient.new

doc = Nokogiri::XML(clnt.get_content(url))
doc.search('html_instructions').each do |html|
  puts html.text
end
```

Which outputs:

```
Head <b>south</b> on <b>S Federal St</b> toward <b>W Van Buren St</b>
Turn <b>right</b> onto <b>W Congress Pkwy</b>
Continue onto <b>I-290 W</b>
[...]
```

The difference is that `inner_html` is reading the content of the node directly, without decoding. `text` decodes it for you. `text`, `to_str` and `inner_text` are aliased to `content` internally in Nokogiri::XML::Node for our parsing pleasure.

Comment: +1, though I don't really think escaping and unescaping is the most efficient.

Comment: Of course it isn't. I've run into it many times decoding RSS, but that was several years ago so I had to remember what I'd done.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your nodes in CDATA:

```
def wrap_in_cdata(node)
    # Using Nokogiri::XML::Node#content instead of #inner_html (which
    # escapes HTML entities) so nested nodes will not work
    node.inner_html = node.document.create_cdata(node.content)
    node
end
```

`Nokogiri::XML::Node#inner_html` escapes HTML entities except in CDATA sections.

```
fragment = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment "<div>Here is an unescaped string: <span>Turn left > right > straight & reach your destination.</span></div>"
puts fragment.inner_html
# <div>Here is an unescaped string: <span>Turn left &gt; right &gt; straight &amp; reach your destination.</span></div>


fragment.xpath(".//span").each {|node| node.inner_html = node.document.create_cdata(node.content) }
fragment.inner_html
# <div>Here is an unescaped string: <span>Turn left > right > straight & reach your destination.</span>\n</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not a great or DRY solution, but it works:

```
puts h.inner_html.gsub("&lt;b&gt;" , "").gsub("&lt;/b&gt;", "").gsub("&lt;div style=\"font-size:0.9em\"&gt;", "").gsub("&lt;/div&gt;", "")
```